# Replacement of strings in a column excluding some words in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to change the words in one of the columns of my data frame such that it will replace all the words except some keywords which I want to leave as it is. 
I tried doing this:

```
df['col]=df['col].where(lambda x: x == ('A'or'B'or'C'),'others')
```

My plan is to replace every word that isn't A or B or C with others.
The code worked for A but B and C were replaced.
How do I go about this please?

NB: I am trying to improve my python skill and have searched the entire stack-overflow  before asking this question. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `x in ('A', 'B', 'C')` instead of `x == ('A'or'B'or'C')`

Comment: you havent found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: Hi Jean, thank you for your fast response. I tried your suggestion and got a 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().' response.

Comment: @RichAd Vectorized version of that is `df['col'].where(lambda x: x.isin(('A', 'B', 'C')), 'others')`.

Comment: @ayhan It worked! Thank you so much.